# Dynamics CRM 2016 c# use id of not yet existing entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2016

for my project, I have to create multiple Quotes and add products to it.
For performance reasons (about 5000 quotes) I am using "ExecuteMultipleRequest()".

This is about what I've got:

```
var quote = new Quote
{
    QuoteNumber = "123",
    Name = "test123",
    PriceLevelId = new EntityReference(PriceLevel.EntityLogicalName, Pricelevel.Id),
    CustomerId = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, Customer.Id),
};
_requests.Requests.Add(new CreateRequest { Target = quote });

var quoteDetail = new QuoteDetail
{
    QuoteId = new EntityReference(Quote.EntityLogicalName, quote.Id),
    ProductId = new EntityReference(Product.EntityLogicalName, product.Id),
    IsPriceOverridden = true,
    PricePerUnit = new Money(20),
    Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(5),
};
_requests.Requests.Add(new CreateRequest { Target = quoteDetail });
```

My problem is the quote.Id. I know it is empty until the server processes the request and creates the quote.

Is there a way to tell the server it should use the quotes new id for the quotedetail?
Or is my only way to create the quote itself and then create all details?
What can I do to increase performance if I have to  do it this way?

Comment: You can actually set quote.id manually before creating it, and Crm will use that id instead of generating an id itself. Though it's not recommended by Microsoft for optimization purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending CreateRequests explicity, you could change your code to use the [OrganizationServiceContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334504.aspx), which locally tracks changes to objects before submitting them to CRM.

When using the OrganizationServiceContext, you can use [AddRelatedObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.addrelatedobject.aspx) to both add an object and link it to another one:

> Adds a related entity to the OrganizationServiceContext and creates
>   the link that defines the relationship between the two entities in a
>   single request.

Alternatively you could manually call [AddObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.addobject.aspx) and [AddLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.addlink.aspx).

You final code would look similar to the following:

```
using (var context = new OrganizationServiceContext(_serviceProxy))
{
    var quote = new Quote
    {
        QuoteNumber = "123",
        Name = "test123",
        PriceLevelId = new EntityReference(PriceLevel.EntityLogicalName, pricelevel.Id),
        CustomerId = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, customer.Id),
    };
    context.AddObject(quote);

    var quoteDetail = new QuoteDetail
    {
        ProductId = new EntityReference(Product.EntityLogicalName, product.Id),
        IsPriceOverridden = true,
        PricePerUnit = new Money(20),
        Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(5),
    };
    context.AddRelatedObject(quote, new Relationship("quote_details"), quoteDetail);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```